# I just want to put a MapView from kivy inside a screen of my application, being accessed by a button on the initial menu

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, screen, kivy-language

I have a menu with the following buttons:

- programação
- mapa do fundão
- editais
- sair

I just wish to when click on the button, 'mapa do fundão' it carry me to the map(in this case, open the map in other screen)

I have really done a research , but its giving me a strong headache.

My py and kv files are as follow:

### main.py file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.garden.mapview import MapView
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp

bu = Builder.load_file('ence.kv')

class Gerenciador(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Menu(Screen):enter code here
    pass

class Programacao(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        mapview = MapView(zoom=11, lat=50.6394, lon=3.057)
        return MapViewApp ().run()

class Ence(App):
    def build(self):
        return Gerenciador()

Ence().run()
```

### ence.kv - kv file

```
<Gerenciador>
    Menu:
        name: 'menu'
    Programacao:
        name: 'programacao'
    
<Menu>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding:100
        spacing:0
        
        Image:
            source: "logo.png"
            size_hint_y:None
            height:200

        Button:
            text: 'Programação'
            on_release:app.root.current = 'programacao'
        Button:
            text: 'Mapa do Fundão'
            on_release:app.root.current = 'map'  
        Button:
            text: 'Editais'
        Button:
            text: 'Sair'
            on_release:app.stop()

<Programacao>
    name: 'programacao'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to remove `class MapViewApp()` and add the following `class Mapa()`:

## Snippets - py file

```
class Mapa(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(MapView(zoom=11, lat=50.6394, lon=3.057))
```

## Output

[image: Result - MapView]